# The apk rebuild by apktool can not be installed even after zipalign and sign

Tags: apktool, zipalign, apksigner

I need to make hundreds flavors of my app. They have different logos and names. When I use android studio's productFlavor, it always OOM, and cost very long time to build hundreds app.
So I want to make these apps by apktool. `decompile`, `rebuild`, `zipalign`, `apksign`. But I find that, the finally generated apk can not be installed.
The error is:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: ed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
```

```
apktool d my_app.apk decompile
```

change the logo and name.

```
apktool b decompile my_app-rebuild.apk
```

```
zipalign -v 4 my_app-rebuild.apk my_app-align.apk
```

```
apksigner sign --ks my_key.jks --ks-pass pass:my_ks_pass --key-pass pass:my_key_pass --v1-signing-enabled true --v2-signing-enabled true --out my_app_out.apk my_app-align.apk
```

After these works, the my_app_out.apk can not installed.

Answer (score 3):

From the error you [got](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#extractNativeLibs):

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: ed to extract native libraries, res=-2]
```

If set to `false`, then your native libraries must be page aligned and stored uncompressed in the APK.

It's either you need to set `extractNativeLibs` flag to `true` or you need to page align the apk when doing [zipaligning](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/zipalign) by adding `-p` parameter:

`-p : outfile.zip` should use the same page alignment for all shared object files within infile.zip

The zipalign command should be:

```
zipalign -p -v 4 my_app-rebuild.apk my_app-align.apk
```